# Forge SidedProxy is deprecated

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

In main class:

```
@SidedProxy(clientSide = "com.dimacrafter.cilivization.proxy.ClientProxy", serverSide = "com.dimacrafter.cilivization.proxy.CommonProxy")
public static CommonProxy proxy;
```

Warning:

```
'net.minecraftforge.fml.common.SidedProxy' is deprecated
This inspection reports where deprecated code is used in the specified inspection scope
```

Minecraft Client is crashed before mod pre-initialization.
How fix it?

Comment: What Forge version are you using and where did you get it? The @SidedProxy annotation [is not deprecated](https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MinecraftForge/blob/161b47ee75ad6be159cc34c01e30d6bc434ec5d5/src/main/java/net/minecraftforge/fml/common/SidedProxy.java#L57).

Comment: Latest version. I seen this.

Answer (score 3):

According to this gist: https://gist.github.com/xt9/55a04226728cebe729fe37cc7aa9d10f#fml-demonstration
`@SidedProxy` was replaced with `DistExecutor` in Forge for Minecraft 1.13.

Answer (score -1):

`@Deprecated` means that something is there, but you have to expect that someday it will be gone -> *it works for now*.

The warning says that `@SidedProxy` falls under this condition, but the documentation should (if it is any good) give you a hint to a replacement.

Comment: Forge documentation nothing say about it. http://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts/sides/#sidedproxy

Comment: @SidedProxy is not deprecated in any version of Forge I have ever used.